# 意図しない画面遷移？

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

プログラム歴は長いですが、XCode初心者です。
開発環境はXCode8.1 Swift3を使用しています。
Storyboardになるべく依存しない環境を勉強し始めたところです。

２つのUIViewController（画面Ａ，Ｂといいます）があって、それぞれに遷移ボタンを実装し、それが押されると、相手方の画面に遷移するという単純な処理で躓いています。

困っている問題は、２枚目の画面Ｂで、遷移ボタン以外の領域をクリックしても、反対の画面Ａに遷移する点です。

解決しようと検索して下記のリンクを見つけて実行してみましたが、同じ問題が発生してしまいます。
http://docs.fabo.io/swift/uikit/015_uiviewcontroller.html
このコードですと、
　画面Ａ→Ｂで、partialCurl
　画面Ｂ→Ａで、FlipHorizontal
のエフェクトがかかるものと理解しています。ボタンを押したときはその通りの動作をします。
画面Ｂで、 ボタン以外の領域（なぜか画面上方の領域）をクリックすると、「partialCurlの逆」のエフェクトで画面Ａに遷移しており、onClickMyButtonが呼び出されていないことまでは理解しているつもりです。

これは何が起きているのでしょうか？

// 追記です。
当方の手順ですが、
(1) File- New -ProjectでSingle View Applicationを作成
(2) SecondViewController.swiftを作成して、リンク先のコードをコピー。
(3) Swift3でエラーが消えるように修正したコードが以下の通りです。
(4) ViewController.swiftについても、リンク先のコードをコピーして、同じような修正を行いました。
コードの修正で何か間違いを犯していますでしょうか？

当方の環境では、シミュレータ上のiOSデバイス（iphone7など）で現象を確認しています。

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 背景色を設定.
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        // ボタンを作成.
        let backButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 120, height: 50))
        backButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        backButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        backButton.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
        backButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        backButton.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width/2 , y:self.view.bounds.height-50)
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClickMyButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(backButton);
    }

    /*
     ボタンイベント.
     */
    internal func onClickMyButton(sender: UIButton){

        // 遷移するViewを定義.
        let myViewController: UIViewController = ViewController()

        // アニメーションを設定.
        myViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.flipHorizontal

        // Viewの移動.
        self.present(myViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: リンク先の記事は完全にはSwift 3用になっていなかったので、若干こちらで修正したのですが、ご記載のような動作にはなりませんでした。(なお、リンク先の記事には「Back」と記載されたボタンがあるため誤解しそうですが、「画面B」の「Back」ボタンを押すと「(元の)画面A」に「戻る」のではなく、(元の画面Aとは別の)あらたな画面Aを作ってそちらに遷移するだけです。ボタンを何度も押すと画面A→画面B→画面Aその2→画面Bその2→画面Aその3→…といった感じで無限に新しい画面を作り続け、決して元の画面に戻ることはありません。)事象が再現できるような最低限のプロジェクトを作成して、そのコード全体(場合によっては設定内容等も必要かもしれません)をご質問中に追記してください。

Comment: コメントどうもありがとうございます。

Comment: 遷移効果（Transition）を、`UIModalTransitionStyle.partialCurl`以外のものにしてください。そうすると、「遷移ボタン以外の領域をクリックしても、反対の画面Ａに遷移する」ことはなくなります。画面どこでもということではないようですが、あるエリアをユーザがタップすると、モーダル終了するという、Partial Curl独特の振る舞いのようです。ここで誤解なく注目してもらいたいのは、**画面遷移する**のではなく、**モーダル終了する**という点です。この相違をしっかり識別してください。

Comment: TransitionをpartialCurl以外に書き換えたところ、意図した動作になりました！
なるほど、「画面遷移」でなく「モーダル終了する」なので、”partialCurlの逆”のエフェクトなのですね。合点がいきました。
今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @nagonsoftware さん、情報ありがとうございます。ボタン以外の画面全域で反応するのではなく、画面のほぼ上半分で反応するのですね。ボタンの周りばかりを触っていて気がつきませんでした。@caesar さん、余計なお手間をかけましたが、こちらでも同じ事象が確認できました。もう少し時間をとって確認すればよかったですね。反省しております。